# Install Adobe Flash 64-bit in IE8 on W2K8 R2

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer-8, flash-player

The situation.  The BBC iPlayer worked in IE8 before I upgraded to W2K8 R2.  The BBC iPlayer works in Mozilla now!  In IE8 the iPlayer tells me to get Adobe flash, when I go to the Adobe site I get mumbo jumbo about running 32-bit programs in 64-bit OS.

Question: Can you point me to a link to download Adobe flash or a 64-bit OS (IE 8 Browswer).

Comment: This is a particular problem for the combination of 64-bit hardware and the IE 8 which comes with Windows Server 2008 R2.  (Bizarely, Adobe flash worked for the IE 8 you download when you have the original Windows Server 2008)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no version of Adobe Flash Player for 64-bit browsers. There is a pre-release version but I don't think it's really production-ready.

The only solution at the moment is to use the 32-bit version of IE8 which is also included in 64-bit versions of Windows.

Adobe has also a Technote discussing this topic: [Flash Player support on 64-bit operating systems](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html)

**Edit:** If you have problems with the download page you can try to download the installer directly from this URL: [Link](http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_ax.exe)

Comment: I see in Taskmanager iexplore*32 (along with plain iexplore).  What I cannot find anywhere is a link to a download Adobe Flash for my situation, the menus just take me around in circles.  I have tried your Technote link too.

Comment: I just included the direct download url.

Comment: I am grateful for your help.  Unfortunately the BBC iplayer still complains about the adobe flash.  I installed the file supplied by your link.  Then I saw a message Install Failed.  Then I installed it again, no message, but still not working.

Comment: Do other websites which require Flash (like YouTube) work?

Comment: No youTube does not work in IE8 on Windows Server 2008.  I phoned up Adobe, they said that Flash was not supported on Windows Server 2008.  -- Most disappointing of Adobe

Comment: In all fairness, it is a server OS. Browsing on servers is a no-no

Comment: Two matters, arising: Thanks Albic, I downloaded directly from your link - no go.  MarkM, I would be facinated to hear from people with 64-bit Windows 7, IE8 and Adobe.

Comment: I have x64 Win 7 with IE8 and the 32 bit browser works fine with flash.

Comment: @Guy - The Internet Explorer that comes on servers is different from the IE on desktops. If you are using the server as a workstation and not as a server and you have a legit reason to browse from it, perhaps Firefox is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Of all the questions I have ever asked in forums, I think that this is the most far-reaching.

**The problem combination**: 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 (May also apply to 64-bit Windows 7) with IE8 – the version you get with R2 or Windows 7.  In a nutshell the problem is that Adobe Flash is not supported.  Adobe's help line confirm it won't work.  Anyone with an IE8 browser on a 64-bit system will get driven mad if they try to install Adobe Flash.

**The solution** is attention to detail, seeking the 32-bit iexplorer.  It's in the Program Files (x86) note the (x86).  Amazingly if you use this 32-bit iexplorer (even on a 64-bit OS), you can download the Adobe Flash stuff – YouTube will then work.

**The downside**. You will need to Pin the iexplorer in the Programs (x86) to your Taskbar or start menu to get the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The current x64 version of Adobe Flash Player is for Linux only

[Adobe Flash Player 10 for 64-bit](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/64bit.html)

Comment: I just wondered how this post would help me?  If I could remind all answerers that the BBC iPlayer worked on my 64-bit Windows Server 2008 with IE8.  Since I upgraded to R2, with it's new installation of IE8, I cannot get an Adobe flash add-on which does the job

Comment: You could install the 32-bit flash player for now,it works with all browsers,i guess

i'm using 32-bit flash on windows 7 (64-bit) and it works just fine

Comment: I have tried again.  What seems to happen is that the Adobe site detects that I have a 64-bit operating system and IE browser and forces me to this page.  Which then loops and won't take me to a page where I can download a 32-bit driver. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html

Comment: you shouldn't be running the 64-bit version of IE,use the 32-bit instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to go [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/thankyou/?installer=Flash_Player_10_for_Windows_Internet_Explorer). Does it automatically start a download, or does it still say something about being unable to install? If it automatically starts a download, give that a go.

**EDIT:**

I have a couple more things for you to try if my original suggestion does not work.

If you go [here](http://www.softwarepatch.com/internet/flash.html), it will allow you to download the standalone installer. It says that it is Server 2008 compatible. I'm not sure how the 64bit vs. 32bit situation is going to affect this.

I was also able to find a technical article on Adobe's site that stated the following...

> If the ActiveX Control for Flash Player fails to install, download the executable installer.
>   If the information above has not resolved the issue, download the executable Flash Player installer here:
>
> [Download](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/ts/documents/tn_19166/Install_Flash_Player_10_ActiveX.zip) and unzip [Install_Flash_Player_10_ActiveX.zip](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/ts/documents/tn_19166/Install_Flash_Player_10_ActiveX.zip) (Internet Explorer for Windows only)

Comment: I was reading through the comments on other answers and noticed that you already tried installing various things. Make sure you uninstall any other Flash packages first before trying my solution.

Comment: Indeed, I have unistalled by installing the suggestions.  Many of these intalls actually appear in the Program manager, but they don't get the job done - displaying flash.   As I indicate, below, I think their is a fundamental weakness with Adobe, IE8 and 64-bit OS.   One more thing, could I ask for solutions which have been tried and tested on a similar system to mine?

Comment: Thanks for the flash link.  I tried it but it only works with 32-bit iexplorer