# Flash standalone installer for Win 2008/64/ IE8

Tags: 64-bit, flash, windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-8, installer

I am working on a x64 Win2008 server that does not have external network access.  The software I'm working with uses flash, but doesn't install it.

I need to find a standalone flash installer that I can download and push to this box.

If you go to the adobe site, you can select os/architecture, but it wants to install the adobe-downloader to download and install it rather than just allow me to download.

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/70502/install-adobe-flash-64-bit-in-ie8-on-w2k8-r2) pointed to an installer (as part of a sub comment), but the link is dead. Further, the only offline installers available seem to only install the 32-bit version, even on a 64-bit system as seen in the *Control Panel* (below).

Any know where I can find a standalone installer for 2008/x64/IE8?

[image: Screenshot of the Windows Control Panel on a 64-bit system showing 32-bit Adobe Flash installed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that visition the adobe site using Chrome generally allows you to download the files without using the highly annoying Adobe Download Manager.

The other way is to request permission to distribute Adobe products. You have to submit a request and it usually takes a week or two to get approved, but then they give you a linke for direct download.

The final method is to use the link I got from the Adobe distribution permission system: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html

The link is not coded to any particular access or account, so you're not getting "my" version of the app.

Answer (score 3):

You can always download the current Flash Player standalone installers via the following links:

Flash Player, ActiveX (e.g. Internet Explorer)
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_ax.exe

Flash Player, plugin-based (e.g. Firefox)
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player.exe

Answer (score 0):

Despite your server being 64-bit, I assume you would still be using 32-bit flash player.

You can go here to download it (just pick the right version):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/191/tn_19166.html#main_ManualInstaller

P.S. I always find this page by Googling "troubleshoot flash player" (minus the quotes), and it is the first link. I can never seem to find it directly otherwise. This method does not require any permission.

Answer (score -2):

do you use a 32 or 64 bits web browser ?

if you're using a 64 bits browser, there is a version of flash that is compatible with 64 bits web browsers but which is still unsupported by adobe. its name is square.

i don't know by the way if square can be downloaded as a standalone installer.

i think that you could search for standalone installer on adobe website.

i've not tried that but maybe on google too.

i'll give a try to google for "standalone flash installer".

i didn't visit this webpage but i think it could help you

http://www.softwarepatch.com/internet/flash.html  (this is a standalone flash 10 installer for 32 bits internet explorer)